# Angular array of array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've got observable object called user, so:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user;">
{{user.displayName}}
</ng-container>
```

my JSON object looks like:

```
   "id":"MwdM8bak78eE1omf6u04KtqlE2X2",
   "anonymous":false,
   "cardTokens":{
      "EtVcNxAfm00":{
         "4digits":4123,
         "Vendor":"Visa"
      }
   },
   "displayName":"User",
   "role":"user",
```

and i want to show all of users cards, so im using:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="auth.user$ | async as user; else login">
{{user.displayName}}
<ion-item *ngFor="let card of user.cardTokens;">
{{card.4digits}}
</ion-item>
</ng-container>
```

I see user name, but card tokens show me nothing. what should i do to show cards token array?

Comment: The reason why your code doesn't work is, that `cardTokens` is not an Array but a JavaScript Object.
JS Objects are not iterable which is why you need to use either `Object.keys()` or as  @Adrita Sharma pointed out, the `keyvalue` pipe to be able to iterate.

Comment: The issue is that `cardTokens`is NOT an array here. It is an object. You can use the keyvalue pipe for instance to retrieve an iterable key-value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let card of user.cardTokens | keyvalue">
            {{card.value["4digits"]}}
    </ion-item>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxhd39?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: yeah, its working! Could you explain me how can i return "EtVcNxAfm00"?

Comment: {{card.key}}. See the modified demo

Comment: Everything working. Thank you again, i forgor about | keyvalue